# Importing matplotlib does not work

Tags: python, matplotlib

In my terminal window, i open the ipython enviroment, and then type in `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`. The error message I get from doing this is:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-eff513f636fd> in <module>()
----> 1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

/Users/arazipinhas/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in <module>()
     25 
     26 import matplotlib
---> 27 import matplotlib.colorbar
     28 from matplotlib import style
     29 from matplotlib import _pylab_helpers, interactive

/Users/arazipinhas/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py in <module>()
     32 import matplotlib.artist as martist
     33 import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
---> 34 import matplotlib.collections as collections
     35 import matplotlib.colors as colors
     36 import matplotlib.contour as contour

/Users/arazipinhas/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py in <module>()
     25 import matplotlib.artist as artist
     26 from matplotlib.artist import allow_rasterization
---> 27 import matplotlib.backend_bases as backend_bases
     28 import matplotlib.path as mpath
     29 from matplotlib import _path

/Users/arazipinhas/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py in <module>()
     54 
     55 import matplotlib.tight_bbox as tight_bbox
---> 56 import matplotlib.textpath as textpath
     57 from matplotlib.path import Path
     58 from matplotlib.cbook import mplDeprecation

/Users/arazipinhas/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/textpath.py in <module>()
     20 from matplotlib.ft2font import FT2Font, KERNING_DEFAULT, LOAD_NO_HINTING
     21 from matplotlib.ft2font import LOAD_TARGET_LIGHT
---> 22 from matplotlib.mathtext import MathTextParser
     23 import matplotlib.dviread as dviread
     24 from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties

/Users/arazipinhas/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mathtext.py in <module>()
     61 
     62 import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
---> 63 import matplotlib._png as _png
     64 ####################
     65 

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/arazipinhas/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_png.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/../../../libpng15.15.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/arazipinhas/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_png.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I would truly appreciate a way to resolve this issue. All I want to do is get on with my physics, and all this constant computational setback is quite cumbersome and annoying. I should thus appreciate an expedited response from anyone who may be willing to assist.

Comment: How did you install matplotlib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuum recently updated libpng, which caused this breakage. Sorry for the inconvenience.

The way to fix this error is to run in a terminal

```
conda update qt
conda update matplotlib
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/arazipinhas/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_png.so, 2):
Library not loaded: @loader_path/../../../libpng15.15.dylib
```

really simple: Your matplotlib was linked against libpng15, but that isn't found by your run-time. So you might search for that file, `libpng15.15.dylib`. 
If it's missing, your installation is incomplete and you're probably missing the version of libPNG that was used to build matplotlib.

Comment: I used http://continuum.io/downloads to download python. I am not sure how to find the correct version.

Comment: Well, I don't know continuum, so I can't help you. your installation is broken. Maybe you want to tell them.

Other than that, there's a million ways to get python to your OS. You're using OS X, right? Macports might simply be the way to go.

Comment: I am not an expert in the technecalities of computers; I am a scientist, and thus what may be easy for you or another is not so for another.

Comment: @user4437416 same here

Comment: @you used an installer that didn't do its job properly, ie. installing python, matplotlib and all the dependencies. That's how much I can figure this one out on my own. I wish I had better advice, but I know that a lot of my Mac OS X-using peers use macports to get very complex python-based software. I don't know what you originally wanted to get :(

Comment: @user4437416 : the "really simple" came from the "simple" inferring step from program error to problem description that I had to take to give you the answer (ie. the error said the library was not found, and it's nothing less than what I've written in my answer)